# How to use jcabi-aspects Loggable annotation in android?

Tags: android, logging, annotations, aspectj, jcabi

I'm trying to keep track of the entire app flow so I figured using the Loggable annotation on every single method in my code would do the job.

My issue is that I can't seem to understand how to setup form scratch the Loggable option, including(to my limited understanding of it):

- Importing all dependencies with gradle
- Configuring the log4j properties , from inside the code or from a file
- Using a PackageInfo class to log all methods in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago I played around with Gradle and Android SDK in connection with AspectJ in order to help another user. Maybe you want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27057974/1082681).

P.S.: Your question is very general, so my answer is too. This is StackOverflow, please show some code and/or configuration. Give the community a concrete problem to solve and make your own problem reproducible, ideally via an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I really should put more info in the question, no doubt about it.
As for the problem, after reading your great post and realizing that I could settle for Aspectj, I used this great github repo for reference https://github.com/android10/Android-AOPExample.
All and all I think I'd leave the question as is, mostly cause I don't have time to collect the required data, perhaps some day I'll expend the Q or A parts.

Comment: I am glad you liked my post. So if you think your problem has been solved and my answer helped you with it, feel free to accept and upvote it in order to close the question.