# AOP apply Custom Annotation on Overrided Methods

Tags: java, android, annotations, aop, aspectj

I am trying to inject some boilerplate code before a method is called, I have been using AOP for it.

I successfully made one Custom Annotation and now to manage the flow I need to make another and manage the flow. But the Second One throws a NoSuchMethodFound error. I need to annotate an Overrided Method. I tried to annotate a simple method too, but failed to do so. Here's the Aspect Class

```
@Aspect
public class AnnotationAspect {
private static final String TAG = "AnnotationAspect";

private static final String POINTCUT_METHOD =
        "execution(@org.android10.gintonic.annotation.MyAnnotation * *(..))";

@Pointcut(POINTCUT_METHOD)
public void methodToAnnotate() {

}
@Around("methodToAnnotate()")
public Object weaveJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Log.d(TAG, "weaveJoinPoint: Inside the AnnotationAspect Class");
    joinPoint.proceed();
    return null;
}
}
```

Here's the Annotation Class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

And Here's how I am calling it. I also tried the same annotation by calling it on a overrided method like onResume.

```
@MyAnnotation
public void myMethod() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hello myMethod", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Here's the link to full GITHUB repository [Github](https://github.com/dhruvins7/CustomAnnotation)

The Error block

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method aspectOf()Lorg/android10/gintonic/aspect/AnnotationAspect; in class Lorg/android10/gintonic/aspect/AnnotationAspect; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.android10.gintonic.aspect.AnnotationAspect' appears in /data/app/android10.org.viewgroupperformance-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk)
             at org.android10.viewgroupperformance.activity.LinearLayoutTestActivity.myMethod(LinearLayoutTestActivity.java:51)
             at org.android10.viewgroupperformance.activity.LinearLayoutTestActivity.onCreate(LinearLayoutTestActivity.java:45)
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6582)
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2532)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Do you use Spring AOP or AspectJ? You tagged the question "spring", but if your app runs on Android I assume there is no Spring but just Java and AspectJ. Can you please enlighten me? I also need to know how you compile your code and what is on your Android app's classpath (e.g. _aspectjrt.jar_). It would be best to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), optimally on GitHub, but at least here.

Comment: @kriegaex Ok I'll upload the Project on Github and share the link here. And Yes there is no spring only AspectJ used here. Thanks

Comment: @kriegaex here's the link to the full [Github](https://github.com/dhruvins7/CustomAnnotation) Repository and the [blog](https://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/) that I referred to make it

Comment: Sorry, I was ill. I just looked into your GitHub project. I did not build it, though, because I cannot run it on a PC without setting up a full Android development environment with emulator etc. But my guess still is that something about packaging or classpath might be wrong. You do need _aspectjrt.jar_ on the classpath. Is it? I asked you before. ProGuard might also be a problem, if not configured correctly. Maybe you first try without obfuscation and work your way up to a more complex setup.

Comment: The aspectj on android is very unstable. It does not work out of the box. Sometime the classes are not waved, static method error and running it with proguard issue, using databinding and java 8 compatibility are some of the concern. Hope someone will write a plugin which just work with all these things combine. Aspectj in itself is a very powerful thing. It can make life easy in Android development. I think java bytecode is very different from Android bytecode, I am having same problem as you. When I decompile apk it have the aspectj methods but static method error is coming.

Comment: yes, I did face that very same issue. But then I again started the project from scratch and had to apply and configure everything again, then it worked perfectly. I still do not know what the issue was. And It does make life easier, just needs a proper place and reason to implement it

Comment: @johnsmith, your statement "AspectJ on Android is very unstable" is just plain false. And what do you mean by "does not work out of the box"? It needs a special compiler, so you have to configure it correctly. Once you do that, it works perfectly. If sometimes classes are not woven and sometimes they are, it is a problem in your build management or in your AspectJ pointcuts. AspectJ itself is not the problem, the problem sits in front of the PC.

Comment: @kriegaex Sorry I did not mean that aspectj is unstable. I am saying it has problem with Android Studio above 3.0, data binding. github is full of these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for writing this as an answer, but it is the only way to share code. It is just meant to help you on the way, not to answer the question in the first iteration.

So I have recreated your situation in pure Java + AspectJ outside of the Android world so as to see whether the problem is your code or something other, such as compilation, packaging, deployment, runtime classpath on the target device.

**Marker annotation:**

I used the package name given in your pointcut.

```java
package org.android10.gintonic.annotation;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR })
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.android10.gintonic.annotation.MyAnnotation;

public class Application {
  @MyAnnotation
  public void myMethod() {
    System.out.println("Hi there!");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().myMethod();
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class AnnotationAspect {
  private static final String POINTCUT_METHOD =
    "execution(@org.android10.gintonic.annotation.MyAnnotation * *(..))";

  @Pointcut(POINTCUT_METHOD)
  public void methodToAnnotate() {}

  @Around("methodToAnnotate()")
  public Object weaveJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
    joinPoint.proceed();
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.myMethod())
Hi there!
```

So the intermediate result is that your annotation and aspect both look okay. The problem must be elsewhere. My first guess, as mentioned in my previous comments, is that *aspectjrt.jar* is missing on the classpath on the target device.

---

**Update:** Maybe you should use the Gradle AspectJ plugin mentioned in [my old answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27057974/1082681) which I just remembered. The problem you have and the error message seem to be the same.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. But I tried searching for _aspectjrt.jar_ and haven't been able to achieve the missing classpath error. I checked the whole project thoroughly twice now. In android environment I don't need to define a classpath, But then also I checked it twice now. Each and Everything Seems well.

Comment: So? I put time and effort into my answer, maybe you want to be as polite as giving me some feedback on my update, too.

Comment: I am so sorry, Well I did the same thing as you, I started the project from scratch and also added the plugin and well somehow this time it compiled and built successfully. Thanks for your help.